# Custom Claims and Firebase Security Access error Error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

so i've built a frontend and now i'm working on a backend that has security rules based on custom claims. I'm getting an error that i can't understand. I've run the callable functions and logged out and back in but i still get an error message when i try to change document details. I'm trying to edit a document in firestore, a document belonging to the user. So its either the user makes a change or an admin can make a change.

edit submission:

```
 const onSubmit = async () => {
    const editRef = doc(db, `images/${imageID}`);
try {
        await updateDoc(editRef, {
          aLabels: aLabels,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        toast.error("Something went wrong");
      }
}
```

`adminClaims.js`

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.setAdminClaims = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const adminUIDs = [
    "pyqPlr3BT7LwzxBerxi1seqDrv6x"
  ];

  await Promise.all(
    adminUIDs.map((uid) =>
      admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { admin: true })
    )
  );

  res.send("Done configuring rules");
});
```

firestore security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if false; //line 5
    }
match /images/{image} {
    allow read: if true;
      allow create: if isLoggedIn() //line 16
      allow update, delete: if isLoggedIn() && isOwner() || isAdmin() 
    }

function isLoggedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function isOwner() {
      return request.auth.uid == resource.data.user
    }

    function isAdmin() {
      return request.auth.token.role.admin == true
    }
}
```

Error message

> PERMISSION_DENIED:  false for 'update' @ L5, evaluation error at
> L16:32 for 'update' @ L16, false for 'update' @ L5, Property role is
> undefined on object. for 'update' @ L16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit: your token doesn't have a `role` property, so your `isAdmin` function fails:

```
function isAdmin() {
  return request.auth.token.role.admin == true
}
```

From how you're setting the custom claim the function in the rules should be:

```
function isAdmin() {
  return request.auth.token.admin == true
}
```